# Numerous scenes with numerous meshes out of 1 array

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm creating a mesh per json object stored in an array containing 100 of them, so I want to add 100 meshes to the scene, and I've got plans to even add to that later on.

This puts an enormous strain on my project in terms of performance, as you could imagine. So, I'm trying to figure out how to cut this array up in 10 manageable parts, and have 10 of these `"Planet"` objects be added per scene. So there'd be 10 scenes with each scene containing 10 meshes.

I have no idea if this is even doable since this is my first work on three.js. How do I go about it? My code:

```
 var scene1 = new THREE.Scene();
 var scene2 = new THREE.Scene();
 var scene3 = new THREE.Scene();
 var scene4 = new THREE.Scene();
 var scene5 = new THREE.Scene();
 var scene6 = new THREE.Scene();
 var scene7 = new THREE.Scene();
 var scene8 = new THREE.Scene();
 var scene9 = new THREE.Scene();
 var scene10 = new THREE.Scene();

var data = [{
        "Planet": "1",
    }, {
        "Planet": "2",
    }, {
        "Planet": "3",
    }
    // this continues up until planet 100
];

//this adds 100 meshes to the scene
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map: loader.load('image.jpg') });
    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(30, 50, 50);

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    //random x and z positions so they don't spawn on same spot
    mesh.position.x = THREE.Math.randInt(-500, 500);
    mesh.position.z = THREE.Math.randInt(-500, 500);
    scene1.add(mesh);
}
```

Edit:
My apologies for not being clear enough as I should have been. The main goal is actually having the functionality of switching through 10 scenes, and seeing 10 "planets" in each scene based on the `data` array. I've written this code so that it's up to the user to determine which scene is to be rendered and which aren't. Rendering and seeing 100 planets in one scene isn't just horrible for the performance, it's not what my project needs to look like.

```
var userInput = 1; 
     if (userInput === 1) {
         renderer.render(scene1, camera);
     } else {
         renderer.render(eval('scene' + userInput), camera);
     }
```

Comment: First be aware that in your code, you're currently only setting up scene10. scene1-scene9 are currently undefined.

Comment: Thank you, yes I overlooked that when drafting the code for this question. I've updated my original question with the fix, so as to avoid confusion for later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your specific question, you would probably start by storing the scenes in an array:

```
// Setup scenes
var scenes = [];
for(var i=0;i<10;i++) {
    scenes.push( new THREE.Scene() );
}
```

Then assign the meshes to a scene based on your counter:

```
//this adds 100 meshes to the scene
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    ...
    var sceneIndex = Math.floor(i/10);
    var curScene = scenes[sceneIndex];
    curScene.add(mesh);
}
```

But I'm not sure what your goal is here in terms of improving performance. Is there more code involved than what you've shown? If you still plan on rendering all 10 scenes simultaneously, this won't be any faster than having a single scene.

Comment: I updated my question with more information. I thought with the code I provided in the edit that that'd bypass the render problem, but that doesn't do it at all. The page's load time is horrible even when userInput = 1. scene1 has only 10 planets. Would your code need to still look the same after taking a glanse at my edited question?

Comment: After seeing your edit, the code I've posted would only be a code-quality improvement over what you have. No performance gains there. Regarding the page load time, try moving the var loader/material/geometry outside of the loop and see if that improves the load time. In this specific code example, you only need 1 instance of the loader, and probably only 1 instance of the texture, material and geometry (although that may change depending on where you take this next.)

Comment: Unfortunately, moving the loader out of the loop doesn't look to enhance load time, but right now I'm worried more about getting your code to work because I'm not sure as how to implement it. I've made a a fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/L6bu6b2f/ where I'm simplifying my code for you. Could you show me there how to achieve what I wanted as described in the original question?

Comment: I don't see any noticeable performance or load-time issues with this code. Everything seems to load pretty much instantly and renders very fast. Anyway here is a jsFiddle with the implementation I've referred to: [https://jsfiddle.net/c5n9ugyv/7/](https://jsfiddle.net/c5n9ugyv/7/)

Comment: Hmm, looks exactly what I wanted. Thank you! I played around with your sent fiddle to see if I can add specific meshes to specific scenes, and I'm glad to see that's easily done with eg `scenes[4].add(mesh2)`.

Comment: How would you exclude the mesh being added to a specific scene in the for loop? Like here, `sceneIndex = Math.floor(i/10); 
        scenes[sceneIndex].add(mesh);`
How would you exclude it being added to say `scenes[0]`?

Comment: Use a conditional IF statement: `if(sceneIndex==0) { ...do this only for scene-0 }`, or `if(sceneIndex!=0) { ...dont do this for scene-0... }`